# Swift: receive UDP packet using Network framework

Tags: swift, networking

I'm studying swift 5.6 Network framework. For this I have a Java-based server, that waits a udp packet of size 64 at localhost port 10000 and sends it back to localhost port 20000. Here is my implementation for Swift :

```
import Foundation
import Network

class UdpConnection {
    private var connection: NWConnection?
    private var isConnectionReady = false
    
    init?(host: String, port: UInt16) {
        self.connection = NWConnection(
            host: NWEndpoint.Host(host),
            port: NWEndpoint.Port(integerLiteral: port),
            using: .udp
        )
        
        let connectionEstablishWaiter = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        
        self.connection?.stateUpdateHandler = { [weak self] (newState) in
            switch (newState) {
            case .ready:
              self?.isConnectionReady = true
            default :
              self?.isConnectionReady = false
            }
            
            connectionEstablishWaiter.signal()
          }

        self.connection?.start(queue: .global())
        
        switch connectionEstablishWaiter.wait(timeout: .now() + 1) {
        case .timedOut:
            return nil
        default:
            ()
        }
    }
    
    func sendUDP(content: Data) {
        let sema = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        
        self.connection?.send(content: content, completion: NWConnection.SendCompletion.contentProcessed(({ (NWError) in
            if (NWError == nil) {
                print("Data was sent to UDP")
            } else {
                print("ERROR! Error when data (Type: Data) sending. NWError: \n \(NWError!)")
            }
            sema.signal()
        })))
        
        sema.wait()
    }

    func receiveUDP() {
        self.connection?.receiveMessage { (data, context, isComplete, error) in
            if (isComplete) {
                if let data = data {
                    print("Receive is complete : \(data.count)")
                } else {
                    print("Data == nil")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my test app :

```
import Foundation


if let udpRequestConnection = UdpConnection(host: "127.0.0.1", port: 10_000) {
    print("connection established OK")
   
    if let udpResponseConnection = UdpConnection(host: "127.0.0.1", port: 20_000) {
        let data = Data(count: 64)
        udpResponseConnection.receiveUDP()
        
        udpRequestConnection.sendUDP(content: data)
        print("sent")
    }
} else {
    print("connection establishing FAILURE")
}
```

I see no packet received and moreover I see a strange picture in Wireshark :
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Why is there an ICMP packet ? What am I missing to get this UDP ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems that I got the misunderstanding -> NWConnection ctor is responsible for setting outbound connection params. So to listen to UDP stream I need the following implementation :

```
import Foundation
import Network
import Combine

class UDPListener: ObservableObject {
    
    var listener: NWListener?
    var connection: NWConnection?
    var queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)
    /// New data will be place in this variable to be received by observers
    @Published private(set) public var messageReceived: Data?
    /// When there is an active listening NWConnection this will be `true`
    @Published private(set) public var isReady: Bool = false
    /// Default value `true`, this will become false if the UDPListener ceases listening for any reason
    @Published public var listening: Bool = true
    
    /// A convenience init using Int instead of NWEndpoint.Port
    convenience init(on port: Int) {
        self.init(on: NWEndpoint.Port(integerLiteral: NWEndpoint.Port.IntegerLiteralType(port)))
    }
    /// Use this init or the one that takes an Int to start the listener
    init(on port: NWEndpoint.Port) {
        let params = NWParameters.udp
        params.allowFastOpen = true
        self.listener = try? NWListener(using: params, on: port)
        self.listener?.stateUpdateHandler = { update in
            switch update {
            case .ready:
                self.isReady = true
            case .failed, .cancelled:
                // Announce we are no longer able to listen
                self.listening = false
                self.isReady = false
            default:
                ()
            }
        }
        self.listener?.newConnectionHandler = { connection in
            self.createConnection(connection: connection)
        }
        self.listener?.start(queue: self.queue)
    }
    
    private func createConnection(connection: NWConnection) {
        self.connection = connection
        self.connection?.stateUpdateHandler = { (newState) in
            switch (newState) {
            case .ready:
                self.receive()
            case .cancelled, .failed:
                // Cancel the listener, something went wrong
                self.listener?.cancel()
                // Announce we are no longer able to listen
                self.listening = false
            default:
                ()
            }
        }
        self.connection?.start(queue: .global())
    }
    
    func receive() {
        self.connection?.receiveMessage { data, context, isComplete, error in
            if error != nil {
                return
            }
            guard isComplete, let data = data else {
                return
            }
            
            self.messageReceived = data
            print("Rx data size = \(data.count)")
            if self.listening {
                self.receive()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        self.listening = false
        self.connection?.cancel()
    }
}
```

With this I am able to get the UDP response I expect.